# how to understand this continuation?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

```
(let ([x (call/cc (lambda (k) k))])
    (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))  => "hi"
```

How can I write the executing steps of this continuation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `call/cc` operator is used to call a given procedure with the *current continuation* (hence the name `call-with-current-continuation`). So to understand how it works, we need to know what the current continuation is.

In your program, at the point that the `call/cc` is executed, the continuation looks like this:

```
CONT = (let ([x HOLE])
         (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
```

where `HOLE` is a placeholder for a value to plug in. In other words, the continuation is the remaining computation. You can stick a value into the continuation if you want to progress.

Now, `call/cc` captures this continuation and passes it to the procedure `(lambda (k) k)`. You can see that this procedure just immediately returns the continuation. So the program reduces to:

```
(let ([x CONT])
  (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
```

Applying a continuation captured by `call/cc` replaces the current computation with that continuation plugged with the value you give it. So the application `(x (lambda (ignore) "hi"))` turns into:

```
(let ([x (lambda (ignore) "hi")])
  (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
```

and the rest should follow from what you already know about lambdas and application.

Answer (score 3):

In the first line `[x (call/cc (lambda (k) k))]` we're creating a new continuation which is bound to the `k` parameter in the received `lambda`. That `k` is returned and in turn bound to the `x` local variable - therefore, `x` is a continuation.

In the second line, `x` is called with a single-argument `lambda`; the argument is  ignored and the result of invoking `(lambda (ignore) "hi")` is `"hi"`, which is finally returned as the result of the continuation. This is equivalent to simply calling:

```
(call/cc
 (lambda (k)
   (k "hi")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does this expression evaluate to "hi" ?

```
(let ([x (call/cc (lambda (k) k))])
  (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
```

The first step is to decide what `k` looks like:

```
(define k
  (lambda (value)
    (let ((x value))
      (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))))
```

We see immediately that this is the same as

```
(define k
  (lambda (x)
    (x (lambda (ignore) "hi"))))
```

But, I failed to mention one little detail.  If `k` is
ever invoked, it is as if it were invoked in tail position.

So `(f (k 3))` for all continuations `k` built by `call/cc` is the
same as `(k 3)`.  That is always a little bit tricky.

So, let's use `lambda^` to mean that the function it introduces
is to be invoked as if it were in tail position.

```
(define k
  (lambda^ (x)
    (x (lambda (ignore) "hi"))))
```

Now we know what `k` is, we also need to know that returning
out of `(call/cc (lambda (k) k))` is really using a default.

It should have been written correctly as

```
(call/cc (lambda (k) (k k))).
```

There is always an implied invocation of k at the top of the
body of the lambda expression passed to `call/cc`.

We know what `k` is.

So, we know that this must be the same as, (for ease of reading let's
turn the `x`'s in the argument position into `y`'s.)

```
((lambda^ (x) (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
 (lambda^ (y) (y (lambda (ignore) "hi"))))
```

So, we evaluate both positions to functions.

Once we invoke the function in function position,
we are done, since it is headed by `lambda^`  So, we need to know that

```
((lambda^ (x) (x (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
 (lambda^ (y) (y (lambda (ignore) "hi"))))
```

evaluates to, substituting for `x`

```
((lambda^ (y) (y (lambda (ignore) "hi")))
 (lambda (ignore) "hi"))
```

and one more step, substituting for `y`

leads to

`((lambda (ignore) "hi") (lambda (ignore) "hi"))`, which ignores
its argument and returns "hi"